# Call a dataframe from another function?

Tags: python, dataframe, oop

I have defined class which has 2 modules. 1 module to do preprocessing, another module to send data to mqtt. But I am not able to call dataframe in 2nd module from 1st module. Code I have written:

```
class bruh:
  def preproc(self):
      final = (*final dataframe after preprocessing*)
  def senddata(self):
      message = final (**here the final is not getting sent**)
  def runcode(self):
      self.preproc()
      self.senddata()
a=bruh()
a.runcode()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Those are functions/methods, not modules. - https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-module ... https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#index-42 -

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#a-first-look-at-classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to set this dataframe as class attribute. Change the code like this

```py
class bruh:
  def preproc(self):
      self.final = (*final dataframe after preprocessing*)
  def senddata(self):
      message = self.final (**here the final is not getting sent**)
```

Notice the `self` keyword before `final`. When you will make your `final` dataframe a class attribute, it will be accessible by all functions.

Comment: should i add self. to every steps inside preproc? or only in the final line?

Comment: No. You wouldn't need to. Let's take a step back and understand what does the `self` keyword do. [Here's a good explanation of it](https://www.programiz.com/article/python-self-why)